# External disk partitions with identical UUIDs

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk, uuid

I have two external USB drives of the same make and model, and one of them is driving me slightly nuts by never being assigned a UUID (or, at least, it doesn't show up in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`). What could cause that, and how can I fix it?

FWIW, ext2fs on Windows was never able to assign a drive letter to that disk automatically, and always complains that "GUID is 0" when I assign a drive letter to it manually (but after that it works fine).

The device block information seems to pinpoint the problem (thanks @dchirikov): **Both partitions have the same UUID.** How can I fix this?

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sd[ab]*
/dev/sda: PTUUID="0002866e" PTTYPE="dos" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Elements1" UUID="DACC0069CC0041ED" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="83529362" PTTYPE="dos" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Elements2" UUID="DACC0069CC0041ED" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Comment: What `blkid /dev/sd*` shows?

Comment: Identical as in what — same brand? Same content?

Comment: You ran the command @dchirinkov recommended with root, right?

Comment: The *drives* have different IDs. The *filesystems* have identical UUIDs. Nitpick perhaps, but there is a difference here.

Comment: Good point @MichaelKjörling - Found a solution based on partitions rather than drives.

Answer (score 0):

Two-part solution:

Windows/ext2fs: Use the option to create a mount point which will be enabled at boot. This seems to work around the UUID (only tried one boot so far, so we'll see).

Linux/fstab: Simply configure mount points by label:

```
LABEL=Elements1 /media/elements1 [...]
LABEL=Elements2 /media/elements2 [...]
```